# How do I keep a database running across stages in Azure Pipeline/DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 3 stages which basically do `linting`, `data preparations`, and `building`.

I would like to have `linting`, `data prepartions` to run in parallel at the same time, and `building` requiring (`dependsOn`) both `linting`, `data prepartions` to complete before starting.

I got this at the very beginning for the resource declaration.

```yaml
resources:
  containers:
    - container: mongo
      image: mongo
      ports:
        - 23015:23015
```

It seems that the `services` here cannot be at any higher level, making it synctatically impossible to have something that "keeps running" across either jobs

```yaml
  jobs:
    - job: BuildDeploy
      displayName: Build & Deploy

      services:
        mongo: mongo
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you want to use jobs (not stages) (as it is on your code).

If you want to run some jobs in parallel you need to set explicit not dependency via `dependsOn: []`. Once this is done, you need to dependsOn your final job.

```
- job: linting
  dependsOn: []
  steps:
  - .....
- job: dataPrepartions
  dependsOn: []
  steps:
  - .....
- job: BuildDeploy
  displayName: 'Build and deploy'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  dependsOn:
  - linting
  - dataPrepartions
  condition: |
    and
    (
      eq(dependencies.linting.result, 'Succeeded'),
      eq(dependencies.dataPrepartions.result, 'Succeeded'),
    )
```

please take a look also [here](https://elanderson.net/2020/05/azure-devops-pipelines-depends-on-with-conditionals-in-yaml/)